# How to access nested property from ngrx selector Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-selectors

Initial Data definition and Interface:

```js
export interface IInitialData {
    version: {
        patch?: string;
        Version: string,
        build: number,
    };
}

export const initialStateInitialData = {
    version: {
        build: 0,
        Version: '1',
    },
};
```

I have the following selectors in the selectors file:

```js
export const selectInitialDataFeature = createFeatureSelector<IInitialData>('initialData');`

export const selectInitialData = createSelector(
    selectInitialDataFeature,
    initialData => {
        return initialData;
    },
);

export const selectInitialDataVersion = createSelector(
    selectInitialData,
    initialData => {
        return initialData.version.Version;
    },
);
```

Accessing 2nd one from component file:

```js
public version$ = this.store.select(selectInitialDataVersion);
```

And from template file:

```html
[value]="version$ | async"
```

This works fine.

However, following returns error "Unresolved variable version"

```js
public initialData$ = this.store.select(selectInitialData);
```

```html
[value]="initialData$.version.Version | async"`
```

How do I access the variable version.Version in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(initialData$ | async) as myInitialData">
  <my-component [value]="myInitialData.version.Version">
  </my-component>
</ng-container>
```

You are trying to access the value of your `Observable` without subscribing it, which in this case, before using the `async` pipe

Or if you don't want to handle that in your template html, you could do it in your .ts file

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select(selectInitialData).subscribe(
   (myData) => this.initialData = myData.version.Version; 
  );
}
```

```html
<
 ...
 ...
 [value]="intialData">
```

Comment: So I pretty much always gotta wrap in an `ng-container` if i wanna pull the value?

Comment: No, it could be a div or anything, You use `ng-container` when you don't want render an element in your template HTML, is only holding the validation of your ngIf, if it is true, then, it renders your desire element. It acts as a dummy component

Comment: this is very helpful, thanks. but do you know of any other workaround? some way to set `myInitialData` in the component class itself?
or perhaps a method to call on `initialData$` which would give access to inner props?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the async pipe directly after the observable, then then access the properties:

```js
[value]="(initialData$ | async).version.Version"
```